# How to implement malloc, if implementation requires declaring a linked list for used blocks?

Tags: c

I am using a pre-declared static array as "memory", and need to maintain a "ledger" of which bytes are used and can't be returned in malloc.

All the implementations I read online require me to declare structs of memory blocks, and make a linked list of used memory blocks.

Problem is, you can't have a linked list without malloc.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You would use sbrk (legacy) or mmap.

There is an implementation with sbrk in the book "The C Programming Language".

Comment: what if it is uC without OS and brk implemented

Comment: I take it he is a student learning C on UNIX. If you know the answer to your question, please do share it.

Comment: @MaximeVernier The OP is using `a pre-declared static array as "memory"` which doesn't require additional host/OS level allocations.

Comment: @MaximeVernier I think that purpose of this exercise is to learn how to implement some simple malloc.

Comment: @dxiv I think you are right, linked list made me think about dynamic allocation right away.

Comment: @P__J__ Simple malloc which uses the allocated memory without doing a system call ok I get it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

> All the implementations I read online require me to declare structs of memory blocks, and make a linked list of used memory blocks.
>
> Problem is, you can't have a linked list without malloc.

The idea is to have a linked list of **available** memory (rather than a linked list of allocated memory), in which case you can use the available memory itself to store the data.

As a sidenote, since you're using a `static` Array, you could use a bitmap instead of a linked list, reducing the memory needed to a single bit per memory "unit".

Using a bitmap could simplify a lot of the issues that might occur as you use your memory, such as memory defragmentation logic, etc'.

Depending on your use case, you may set use a bit per 16 bytes, 32 bytes or even a page (what is a normal allocation size?).

Using 16 byte units you would get a ratio of 1:128 between usable memory and metadata memory, which isn't horrible but isn't amazing. Using 32 bytes per bit would get you to 1:256, which improves your ratio but may cause some allocations to allocate more memory than they actually need... this really depends on your use case.